# AngularJS JavaScript Parsing part of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following JSON. 
I have a parameter to give and I need to return all the number.

If I give "BUS", I need to return1,38,44,58

Example of **JSON**:

```
{  
   _id:"23456789",
   result:[  
      [  
         "Car",
         [  
            [  
               2,
               3,
               4,
               6
            ],
            [  
               3,
               4,
               444,
               123
            ],
            [  
               43,
               34,
               91446,
               344473
            ]
         ]
      ],
      [  
         "Bus",
         [  
            [  
               1,
               38,
               4458,
               0981
            ]
         ]
      ],
      [  
         "Moto",
         [  
            [  
               5,
               43,
               41440,
               804444
            ]
         ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
    var coordinates = [];
    console.log("tag :"+tag); // tag is the parameter "Bus", "Car" or "Moto"
    $http.get('http://myserver:1234/bbox/'+id)
                    .success(function (response) {
                var point = {};
                // Don't know how to catch a specific word (i.e Car or BUS or Moto)
                for (var i in response){
                    var pointName =  response.result[i][0];
                    coordinates.push(response.result[i][1]);
                    points[pointName] = coordinates;
                }

    })
    .error(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
     });
```

`tag` is already set with only one parameter.
Just need to return the coordinate for one given.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty strange structure for JSON response, but you can still extract necessary data. For example using `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
var coordinates = response.result.filter(function(el) {
    return el[0] === tag;
})[0][1][0];
```

For `tag` equal to "Bus" above code will give you `[1, 38, 4458, 981]` array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could I do something like                     var coordinates = response.result.filter(function(el) {
                        var res = el[0] === tag;
                        console.log("res "+res);
                    })[0][1][0];   ????

Comment: Not sure I follow. Filter must return boolean value.

Comment: OOOps my mistake, it works! About the tag "Car", I will also get all the points?

Comment: Looks like you actually need `filter()[0][1]` to get all points array (array of array of all points).